# How to use catcodes in a macro/environment

Tags: package-writing, catcodes

I want to use catcodes in an environment and the catcodes shall be changed for a very short part in the document.

MnWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}


\NewEnviron{Lied}[3][]{
\subsection{#3 - Variant: #2}
{%catcode
\catcode`\&=13%
\def&{\\}%
\catcode`\==4%
\fbox{
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Meta data name = Meta data value &
\hline
#1
\end{tabular}
}%fbox
}%end catcode

\BODY
}

\begin{document}
{
%catcode
%\catcode`\&=13
%\def&{\\}
%\catcode`\==4
\begin{Lied}[
abc = def &
123 = 456 &
khi = jkl &
Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing
\end{Lied}
}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work. If I uncomment the catcodes inside the document-environment, and comment out the part in the Lied-environment, it doesn't work either. It works, if I also switch the header line of the tabular to `Meta data name & Meta data value \\`. In theory the expanded table looks like this:

```
Meta data name & Meta data value \\
\hline
abc = def &
123 = 456 &
khi = jkl &
Herr = Michael Mustermann
```

This is a mix of both notations (`& + \\` and `= + &`) and produces this output:
[image: Output]
This doesn't make any sense. It looks like the tabular behaves somehow like an edef, preventing the catcodes to take effect later. But then, the first version should work.

On a side note: How can I change the size of images in the question.

Comment: a NewEnviron enviroment body is a macro argument so unlike a standard environment you need to set catcodes before the body is scanned

Comment: `\NewEnviron{Lied}[3][]{
\subsection{#3 - Variant: #2}
{%catcode
\catcode\`\&=13%
\def&{\\}%` will generate errors when used as you need `\def&`with an active `&`not a normal tabular `&`

Comment: Is there a reason for: (a) using `&` instead of ``\\``; (b) using `\NewEnviron` instead of a standard `\newenvironment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some comments. Whenever you do

```
\NewEnviron{foo}[0]{%
  <something>
  \BODY
}
```

you're misusing the tool, which is useful when you want to do some processing to `\BODY` not just to reinsert it in the input stream unchanged.

I also see no reason for playing with catcodes, which is always a bit dangerous. What's the advantage of typing

```
abc = def &
```

over

```
abc & def \\
```

which is as easy to input?

Anyway, here's a working implementation. You must change the catcodes also when you define the environment; then you need to change them back, redo the assignments before the environment is started and revert after.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\catcode`& \active
\catcode`= 4

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Lied}{O{}mm}{%
  \subsection{#3 -- Variant: #2}
  \def&{\\}%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Meta data name = Meta data value &
    \hline
    #1
    \end{tabular}
  }%fbox
  \par
}{\par}

\catcode`= 12
\catcode`& 4

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 4 \catcode`& \active}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 12 \catcode`& 4 }

\begin{document}

\begin{Lied}[
  abc = def &
  123 = 456 &
  khi = jkl &
  Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing
\end{Lied}

\end{document}
```

Note the missing `=` sign in the catcode assignments, which would be invalid when `=` has catcode 4.

[image]

If you really need `\NewEnviron`, I suggest instead `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and its `b` argument type, so you can use the parameter (in this case `#4`) instead of `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\catcode`& \active
\catcode`= 4

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Lied}{O{}mm +b}{%
  \subsection{#3 -- Variant: #2}
  \def&{\\}%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Meta data name = Meta data value &
    \hline
    #1
    \end{tabular}
  }%fbox
  \par
  #4% do some processing here?
  \par
}{}

\catcode`= 12
\catcode`& 4

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 4 \catcode`& \active}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 12 \catcode`& 4 }

\begin{document}

\begin{Lied}[
  abc = def &
  123 = 456 &
  khi = jkl &
  Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing
\end{Lied}

\end{document}
```

---

If you need that `=` and `&` have the usual role in the environment and only be special in the first argument (which I believe is quite strange syntax), you can juggle a bit with catcodes.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\catcode`& \active
\catcode`= 4

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Lied}{O{}mm}{%
  \begingroup
  \subsection{#3 -- Variant: #2}
  \def&{\\}%
  \fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Meta data name = Meta data value &
    \hline
    #1
    \end{tabular}
  }%fbox
  \endgroup
  \catcode`& 4 \catcode`= 12
  \par
}{\par}

\catcode`= 12
\catcode`& 4

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 4 \catcode`& \active}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Lied}{\catcode`= 12 \catcode`& 4 }

\begin{document}

\begin{Lied}[
  abc = def &
  123 = 456 &
  khi = jkl &
  Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing $a=b$

\begin{tabular}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{tabular}
\end{Lied}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you *really* need `\NewEnviron`, a different approach is to be taken, namely replacing tokens rather than changing category codes.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Lied}{O{}mm +b}
 {
  \subsection{#3 -- Variant: #2}
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { & } { \\ }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { = } { & }
  \fbox
   {
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    Meta ~ data ~ name & Meta ~ data ~ value ~ \\
    \hline
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \end{tabular}
   }%fbox
  \par#4\par
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Lied}[
  abc = def &
  123 = 456 &
  khi = jkl &
  Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing $a=b$

\begin{tabular}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{tabular}
\end{Lied}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know, that I kind of abuse the NewEnviron. I redefine NewEnviron for a special use case. So, the structure of the Lied-environment is given.

Comment: The problem is, that this change applies to the complete content of Lied, but it should only apply to the first argument of Lied. I'm considering changing the format of the Lied-environment. Or I write an unpackage routine for the first argument, then reassemble it correctly.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz It would be easy if you give up with `\NewEnviron`, but using standard syntax for the first argument would be much easier.

Comment: I can easily give up on that, the point is only, that it had been defined in before as a `\NewEnviron`. I need to redefine it in my code. So redefining it in whatever way may not break it.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Look at the edits. But still I can't understand what's the reason for `=` as alignment marker and `&` for line ending.

Comment: That did it. The reason, you can see here https://github.com/MaestroGlanz/Lieder-Package under Demoprojekt/Testliederbuch.sty. That is the format, which I use. I can pick content from there by Liederbuch name, Lied name and variant and insert it via command into the document. Now, I need an extra sty-file for creating a catalogue.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz My impression, looking at the documentation, is that the first argument should be in the key-value form and that you'd be much better served with `expl3` features.

Comment: I'm very open to improvements. Feel free to open an issue in Github, how you think, the syntax should be. Back then, when I came up with the syntax, I asked a question for this specific purpose here. I plan to release the package in the next 10 weeks on ctan. Primary goal is now to make an open source kyriale.

Comment: Do you have a good entry point to start reading on key-value form.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want an active `&` in the definition so `\def&` is not an error

```
\catcode`\&13 % space before % here important
\catcode`\=4 % space before % here important
\NewEnviron{Lied}[3][]{
\subsection{#3 - Variant: #2}
{%catcode
\def&{\\}%
\fbox{ %space here?
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Meta data name = Meta data value &
\hline
#1
\end{tabular} %space here?
}%fbox
}%

\BODY
}
\catcode`\=12
\catcode`\&4
```

then you need to switch catcodes locally before the environment is scanned

```
\let\oldLied\Lied
\def\Lied{\catcode`\&=\active\catcode`\=4 \oldLied}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{environ}

\catcode`\&13 % space before % here important
\catcode`\=4 % space before % here important
\NewEnviron{Lied}[3][]{
\subsection{#3 - Variant: #2}
{%catcode
\def&{\\}%
\fbox{ %space here?
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Meta data name = Meta data value &
\hline
#1
\end{tabular} %space here?
}%fbox
}%

\BODY
}
\catcode`\=12
\catcode`\&4

\let\oldLied\Lied
\def\Lied{\catcode`\&=\active\catcode`\=4 \oldLied}

\begin{document}
{
%catcode
%\catcode`\&=13
%\def&{\\}
%\catcode`\==4
\begin{Lied}[
abc = def &
123 = 456 &
khi = jkl &
Herr = Michael Mustermann
]{var1}{1}
Nothing
\end{Lied}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is still a difficulty to understand for me, is, when ´\concat\x=y´ is executed. From what I have seen, I have to conclude, that it is not regarded after expansion of all macros, but already on input.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz catcode settings have no effect on tokens.  if you set the catcode of `&` to 13 it says make a `&_13` token _if generating a token from a `&` being read from a file_. it has no effect on any tokens already made.